# TextMeshPro Shader choices difference (when to use)

Tags: unity, text

Actually I can see the visual difference that

- `bitmap/sprite` shows blurry text like this:

[image: bitmap/sprite]

- pink `distance field` seems like missing texture:

[image: distance field]

- `distance field surface` grey:

[image: df surface]

- and lastly `distance field masking/overlay` seems to show the correct/expected result:

[image: df masking/overlay]

so what's the difference between those two? (masking/overlay)

[image: shader choices]